# It is possible to cache all html/php page, except a part of it in browser?

Tags: php, html, caching

Is it possible to cache all page, but do not cache a part of it in the browser?
For example, i have a page with date. Only date is changing daily, the rest of page never changes. How i shall cache such a page in the browser?

Could on the browser cached page contain dynamical content?
Actually, i am new to caching, i do not understand how it works with dynamical content and browser caching. Is this right, that from the moment some dynamic page is cached, it is served always as it was after during the caching, and new dynamic content is not displayed?

I do not ask about the server side caching, only about the browser side caching.

Comment: seems the solutions is to use javascript or css to display the date in the browser cached html/php page div/span.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific tool for ignoring caching a part of the page. but you can do some tricks like:

- You can cache whole page and change the part you want by iframe!
- You can cache whole page and change the part you want by ajax!
- You can cache whole page and change the part you want by a javascript
  file!

i have not checked iframe solution and not sure if it works.

If the js files has cache, you can add a version in their file name like `scripts.v.2.3.js` and load them by version name.

Comment: and sometimes css, because css can display contet, count, and date

Comment: @olga Thank you, but css is not dynamic language, and can't calculate date! but it's possible to calculate in the server and return it to a css file, i think it's not so good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can't really dynamically cache "part" of a file, you can however cache separate assets the more you split your page into separate assets the more you can cache each one of them separately.

- Your index.html could have a cache setting of dont-cache (using the [`Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header)
- Your logo.png could have a long cache set of 10 days

Now if you want to have certain elements changing but the core to stay the same then I believe this would be a better job for JavaScript. What you could do is write a Javascript function to display the date, then you can fully cache the HTML page and the Javascript page and since the raw content never changes (only the manipulation of the `DOM` does you have very little client->server requests.